# three.js: Add an image on the floor of a panorama

Tags: javascript, three.js, panoramas

I am using this code [Panorama](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_panorama_equirectangular.html) and I want to add an image on the floor of this pano. Can somebody guide me on how to do that. The image is very small (256x256)

Comment: You have no clear question here. Do you want to reuse the same picture with another floor ? In this case you can download the texture and change the floor part with your image. Otherwise you can use MeshFaceMaterial and define your images face per face.

Comment: Hey I want to add an image which takes part of the floor. for example I have a floor of 1024x1024 with some texture on it. Now I want to add a 256x256 image on part of the floor(can be centre of the floor) so that I am able to see the texture and image both with image taking some space of the floor

Comment: I have the same question. Trying to add a small circle to the floor of texture in panorama. I tried answer below but it does not seem to give me desired results. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

In order to add an image on the floor you should create a PlaneGeometry, a MeshBasicMaterial and then apply them to a Mesh and then change position and rotationOnAxis.

Example:

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map : texture, opacity : 1, side : THREE.DoubleSide, transparent : true } );
var sprite = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

where texture is the image you want to insert, added via texture loader.

Then you must set the position of the sprite via the position.set function .

For setting the sprite to the north:

```
sprite.position.set(0,-360,0);
```

For setting the sprite to the south:

```
sprite.position.set(0,360,0);
```

The last step is to rotate the sprite 90 degrees so to be visible because otherwise it will be rendered like this | and not [] . So we must do a rotateOnAxis:

```
sprite.rotateOnAxis(  new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 ), THREE.Math.degToRad(90) );
```

If the image is too small you can use:

```
sprite.scale.set( scaleValue, scaleValue, scaleValue );
```

Where scaleValue is a value greater than 0.